# CORS Issue using Fetch - LWC (PreFlight)

Tags: lightning-web-components, cors

We have a LWC which is being hosted on a VF page using Lightning Out - up until December 2022 it was working without issue but it seems we've run into a CORS issue since then (I assume a Spring release issue?).

I tried setting up the LWC directly as an action since I don't think we need the VF page anymore (that was implemented by a developer several years ago) and I'm running into the following error when the fetch method is called which is similar to the one we see on the VF side:

Access to fetch at 'https://sample.example.com/wp-json/xxx/v1/search?keyword=learner&limit=100&page=1' from origin 'https://sample--full3.sandbox.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

We have the following set up:

- Remote site setting (https://sample.example.com)
- CSP Trusted Site Definition (https://sample.example.com, Context: Lightning Experience Pages, Allow site for connect-src = true)

In terms of the fetch callout - it's fairly basic

```
fetch(endPoint,
        {
            method : "GET",
            headers : {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Basic "  + this.wP_Site_AuthorizationToken ,
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((myJson) =>{

            console.log('myJson------>>>'+JSON.stringify(myJson));
```

I've read through many other questions and this blog ([link](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/03/working-with-cors-and-csp-to-call-apis-from-lwc)) from Salesforce which was very helpful but did not solve my issue. Any help that could provided would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems your third party is redirecting, causing it to fail. You'll need to check that you still have the correct endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem while hitting a mock API.
adding the below attributes in fetch Api solved my problem -

```
{
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors"
}
```